# SQL - Limit information in JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, pdo

I have a database with 2 tables, users and news. I'm combining information from the two tables using this SQL:

```
$news = $db->query('SELECT * FROM news LEFT JOIN users ON users.userid = news.userid')->fetchAll();
```

The problem here is that I'm also dragging along information that I have no use for, like password etc. How can I limit the query to only include the name of the user from the users table?

Comment: This is very, very basic SQL. Please take a tutorial.

Comment: Don't use `*`.  List the columns you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I'm using all columns in news table, that's why I'm using the  `*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all columns from one table, and only selected columns from another table, you can use `tablename.*` to get the first, and `tablename.columnname` for the second.

```
SELECT news.*, users.name
FROM news 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.userid = news.userid
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Gordon Linoff mentioned:

```
$news = $db->query('SELECT news.column1, news.column2, users.name FROM news LEFT JOIN users ON users.userid = news.userid')->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing!